# How to split sections in UICollectionView?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I have a UICollectionView which implements pages organized into sections. I want to split a section into two parts and have the following logic. But UICollectionView doesn't seem to be happy with this:

```swift
func splitSection(at index: IndexPath) {
    // this performs the logical split
    self.document.splitSection(at: index)

    if let cv = self.collectionView {
      cv.performBatchUpdates({
        let N = self.document.numberOfSection
        let n = N - index.section - 1
        let range = Range.init(uncheckedBounds: (index.section, n))
        let affectedSections = IndexSet.init(integersIn: range)
        cv.reloadSections(affectedSections)

        let sections = IndexSet.init(integersIn: Range.init(uncheckedBounds: (N-1, 1)))
        cv.insertSections(sections)
      }, completion: { (_) in
        // commit section updates
      })
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

in numberOfSections function return 2
then in cellforitemat function use switch on indexpath.section

Comment: I already have N sections as you can see in the code. self.document.splitSection already splits and increments the number of sections. And it already implements cellForItemAt function to implement sections. I am asking the incremental update logic for collection view.

Comment: what incremental update logic are you talking about?

Answer (score 0):

Ok. So I think I have solved the problem after various experimentation. Here is the final solution in case any one else gets into this problem.

The basic idea is:

1. Move all sections after the the section being split by 1
2. Insert a section after the section being split
3. Delete all the items after the split index from the current section
4. Insert all the items into the newly created section.

The reverse idea can be employed for merging the sections.

Here is the solution:

```swift
func splitSection(at index: IndexPath) {
    # first get a list of deleted and inserted indices as a result of splitting
    let (deleted, inserted) = self.document.splitSection(at: index)

    if let cv = self.collectionView {
      cv.performBatchUpdates({
        let N = self.document.numberOfSection
        // now move over the sections to make space for one more section.
        for idx in index.section+1..<N-1 {
          cv.moveSection(idx, toSection: idx+1)
        }
        // add a new section
        cv.insertSections(IndexSet.init(integer: index.section+1))

        // now perform item movements to finish splitting
        cv.deleteItems(at: deleted)
        cv.insertItems(at: inserted)
      }, completion: { (_) in
        self.document.updateSections()
      })
    }
  }
```